# Heroku integration

Tags: java, heroku, salesforce, apex-code

I am trying for `heroku` integration. Is it possible to login into `heroku` and run heroku commands from java or salesforce apex. Heroku REST API is in ruby. I am not able to understand it. How to run `heroku` command with out using `cmd` or `git`.

Comment: @Vanathi if you cant understand question . you have no right to degrade it.that is very imp. to me  to know this answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the heroku.jar Java based client for the Heroku API:

https://github.com/heroku/heroku.jar

It's still under development, but there is pretty good coverage of the API at this point.

Answer (score 1):

The REST API is just an API so what it's written in shouldn't matter.  You could probably reverse engineer the API from the heroku client (https://github.com/heroku/heroku)

However, bear in mind this API changes.

I guess the question really depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: i want to run my app which is in heroku using UI button click. you mean i have to write api from scratch .can you halp me  in doing the same

Comment: The `heroku` command line application is really for deploying and managing your app, not for "running" it as an end user, especially if your app has a web front end.  You can just add a button to your web app to perform any operation in your app.